# Call a block body of the method dataTaskWithRequest consistently

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlsession

for example:
I have a function

```
-(void) someFunc:(NSString *) searchRequest  {
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
 [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                    {
                  // body block
                                 }
]
     resume];
}
```

and I call someFunc in:

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSString * searchRequest = @"blablabla";
[self someFunc:searchRequest]; 
}
```

In this case, I realized that the body of the block is executed in a separate thread, which leads to data loss.
I want all actions are performed sequentially. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `someFunc:` to return a value look into using a `dispatch_semaphore_t` to block the calling thread until the request is finished and assign the return value to a `__block` qualified variable.

You could also modify `someFunc:` to take a block as an additional argument that would be invoked when the request completes.

```
- (void)someFunc:(NSString *)searchRequest completion:(void(^)(id result))completion {
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
   [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                {
              completion(data);
                             }]
    resume];
}
```

Comment: `someFunc:` should not return a value, inside `completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                {
             
                             }]` I do parsing json file from url and store value in the class property. Then display in tableview. Now it turns out that information from the json file won't load because parsing is performed with a delay in a separate thread.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the block is pushed onto the stack waiting.

Comment: Process the data inside the completion block and then invoke the provided completion on the main thread with the model objects that the table view requires.